# How to find total time hour it takes to travel from A to B to C in terms of angle?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, trigonometry

Question:

Chris swims at 2km/h from A to B across a circular lake at radius 2km, then walks at 3km/h around the edge of the lake from B to C. Determine an expression for total time T hours, it takes for Chris to travel from A to B and then to C, in terms of Θ.

Attempts to solve the problem:

1- I need to visualize it. So here is my poorly drawn diagram:
[image]

2- I am given 2 rate of change, so I am thinking I should use chain rule to related angles and distance and time.
So this is what I did:

$\frac{dθ}{d x} = \frac{dθ}{dt} * \frac{dt}{dx}$

$\frac{dθ}{d y} = \frac{dθ}{dt} * \frac{dt}{dy}$

and then I add them together and somehow I got
$\frac{dθ}{d t} = \frac{1}{-2sin(θ)} + \frac{3}{4}$

and then I do
$\frac{1}{\frac{dθ}{d t}}$ to get to $-2\sin(θ) + \frac{4}{3}$

and I think I can just use anti derivatives to convert back t in terms of theta.
But we have not touched the anti derivative stuff yet.
So I assume this is wrong?
Please help thanks.

Comment: y and x are perpendicular and base respectively so apply $\sin \theta $ and $\cos \theta $ and rearrange them

Comment: @TheStudent i dont understand what do you mean by rerrange them

Comment: i think there is something wrong with diagram , if he walks from $B$ to $C$ how can we show that through the lake? it should be on the boundary of lake

Comment: You know that the distance $AB$ is $4\cos\theta$. You know the speed in water, so you can find the time to get from $A$ to $B$. If $O$ is the centre of the circle, then $\angle BOC=2\theta$, so the distance $BC$ around the edge is $4\theta$. You know the speed on land so you can find the time to get from $B$ to $C$.

Comment: I think that your diagram misses information. Did the question itself come with a diagram? There is definitely information missing : for example, it is not necessary that $AC$ be a diameter according to the question, but you seem to have assumed it.

Answer (score 1):

By Thale's Theorem, the radius of the circle must be 2km. Trigonometry tells us $y=4km\cdot\cos{(\theta)}$. Since from B to C we are not going along x but rather the chord connecting B to C, we need to know the arc length. Geometry tells us the angular measure of chord BC is $2\theta$. Can you prove that? Given a radius of 2km, the length of chord BC is 2km $\cdot  2\theta$.

So if $u_1$ is speed in water and $u_2$ is speed on land, then total time is $t=4km\cdot \cos{(\theta)}/u_1+2km\cdot 2\theta/u_2$

Can you take it from there? You wont' need anti-derivatives.